# Unity is Creating Black Boxes when I look around

Tags: unity, lighting, post-processing

Please help me with this issue. I believe it came about after I finished tweaking post processing behavior in a minor way. If anyone has any idea please share it. I tried to rebake lighting on both scene and lightmaps tabs and it didn't make any difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was Screen Space Reflections property on postprocessing behavior when turned off. Once I turned back on they went away. Hope this helps future developers. Very strange by that it was only having this issue on one scene.